# Facebook Profile Posts on Website

Tags: javascript, facebook

Looking for suggestions how I can achieve this.

I want to display a FB Profile Page(personal page)(not fan page), on my website.
I have tried using a badge but it doesnt display all the posts on my wall, by me and I dont care for how it looks.
I tried using rss but it displays fb notifications and not status changes or photos posted.

Basically waht im after is finding a way to implement my facebook status posts by me on my website and not limiting it to just the last post.

Any ideas? I found a few ways for fan pages but nothing for profile pages.
Site is a regular website and not wordpress, etc.

Comment: user profiles are kind of "private", they are usually not intended to show up in the public just like that. you could read the posts with a user access token, but even if you are using an extended one it will last only for 60 days and then you have to refresh it manually.

Comment: [Something like this](http://retrogram.tk/demos/adamsposts/) (using extended access token) would work for you?

Comment: Yes Adam, I belive something just like that would work great. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

first things first, you need to protect `access_token` from being exposed, this requires `PHP`

We will get the feed using `cURL` (you can use `Facebook-PHP-SDK`, too):

```
<?php

    $user_access_token = '{access_token}'; // A valid user access token or app token
    $userName = '{userName}'; // Facebook username
    $limit = '25'; // Limit posts
    $jsonFeed = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userName.'/posts?fields=id&limit='.$limit.'&access_token='.$user_access_token;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $jsonFeed);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $getPosts = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($getPosts); // decode json

?>

<!-- Basic/required HTML tags, head, style etc.. -->
<!-- body -->

<div id="container">
<h1 class="title">My Timeline Feed</h1>
<?php

      foreach($data->data as $data){

                       $userid_postid = $data->id;
                       $postid = substr($userid_postid, strpos($userid_postid, "_") + 1); // remove the userid because we can't use {userId}_{postId}
                       print '<div class="post-warp"><div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/'.$userName.'/posts/'.$postid.'"></div></div>';
      }  
?>
</div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<!-- / body -->
<!-- / Basic/required HTML tags -->
```

Remember you need an extended `access_token` otherwise you have to re-generate a `token` every 2 hours, the extended `access_token` works for 60 days

Resources:

- [DEMO](http://retrogram.tk/demos/adamsposts/)
- [Embedded Posts Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/)
- [Extending Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending)

Comment: Thanks Adam. Your sample is exactly what im after. Im assuming I cant just copy and paste the code you gave without changing something to reflect my FB page, but what do I change?

Comment: Doing this will the website automatically pull in the new posts? Ill start reading with the links you provided. Its confusing to me though but if I can get it like your sample ill be happy.

Comment: You have to change `$user_access_token` & `$userName`  and it should work

Comment: SO far I got it where it says "my timeline feed". I think im stuck at the whole access token thing as I dont understand it, so ill have to read through it more on how to get one.

Comment: ok, You can generate an `token` using  [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) with permissions `read_stream`, `user_status` & `user_photos` and you can try `var_dump( $getPosts );` to see what errors that Facebook graph returns